# wpf mvvm awaiting method blocks UI while simulating with await Task Delay doesn't

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, async-await

When I do following my UI **doesn't freeze**:

xaml binding:

```
<Button Command="{Binding LongRunningCommand}" />
```

viewmodel:

```
ctor
{
   LongRunningCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(ProcessLongRunningCommand);
}

public DelegateCommand LongRunningCommand { get; private set; }
private async void ProcessLongRunningCommand(object e)
{
   await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

But if I replace the Task.Delay with a real method then my UI **freezes**. This is so weird. Look below for an example:

xaml binding:

```
<Button Command="{Binding LongRunningCommand}" />
```

viewmodel:

```
private readonly IDbAccess _dbAccess;

ctor(IDbAccess dbAccess)
{
   _dbAccess = dbAccess
   LongRunningCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(ProcessLongRunningCommand);
}

public DelegateCommand LongRunningCommand { get; private set; }
private async void ProcessLongRunningCommand(object e)
{
   var callResult = await _dbAccess.LongRunningMethod();

   //adjust viewmodel observablecollection property which binds to a ListBox with callResult
}
```

DbAccess impl:

```
public Task LongRunningMethod(object e)
{
   return Task.Run(() =>
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong please, I lost a lot of time on this...

And btw I know that `async void` not a best practice but I couldn't find a solution to make DelegateCommand asynchronous.

**EDIT**

After more research we concluded that this is a 'render' issue. the LongRunningCommand is asynchronous but the rendering and the binding is taking time and it blocks the UI. I have no idea how to solve this render issue.

Comment: It can freeze in case when  _adjust viewmodel observablecollection with callResult_  doing some heavy UI updates

Comment: I'm just filling the observablecollection with 200 results, it blocks my window. I cant move my window nor resize for 1 second.

Comment: Have you had a look at [this article from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn630647.aspx)?

Comment: Yes we are actually using AsyncCommand, but I changed it to DelegateCommand because this is more commonly known

Comment: Rendering issues are generally solved by [virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This task awaiting deadlock caught me out for a long time too, until I found the solution.

Replace

```
var callResult = await _dbAccess.LongRunningMethod();
```

with

```
var callResult = await _dbAccess.LongRunningMethod().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

See [this blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) by Stephen Cleary for the details why.

Note that the continuation after the await will now be on a different dispatcher context, so anything that directly updates the UI (such as populating an observable collection) must be marshalled back to the UI dispatcher. Many MVVM frameworks contain utilities to help with this - I use the DispatcherHelper class from MVVM Light.

If you're using Resharper, there's a plugin you can install to check that ConfigureAwait() is added to every await statement.

Comment: OP haven't mentioned about deadlock.

Comment: "But if I replace the Task.Delay with a real method then my UI freezes" ... is exactly what a deadlock is.

Comment: this is most likely OP's solution to the problem. Though i would use a configureawait analyzer attached to the project. That's what we do. Wouldn't want build chain to depend on a VS extension to ensure safe code

Comment: Do you have any link to the Resharper plugin?

Comment: Resharper | Extension Manager | "ConfigureAwait Checker"

Comment: ConfigureAwait doesn't solve this. After more research we concluded that this is a 'render' issue. the LongRunningCommand is asynchronous but the rendering and the binding is taking time and it blocks the UI. I have no idea how to solve this render issue but this is out of scope of this topic.